# Sum of a series of binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-k \\
2
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
2
\end{array}\right)}$$

This is an equation from MIT OCW https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/assignments/MIT18_05S14_ps2_solutions.pdf. The solution for problem 5.

It says that "One can show (after a bit of algebra) that this sum is equal to n/3.". But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Begin with $\binom{x}{y}=\frac{x!}{y!(x-y)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short calculation goes like this:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{\binom{n-k}2}{\binom{n-1}2}&=\binom{n-1}2^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-k}2\\
&\overset{*}=\binom{n-1}2^{-1}\binom{n}3\\
&=\frac2{(n-1)(n-2)}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6\\
&=\frac{n}3\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the starred step uses the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Alternatively, but more laboriously, one can

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-k}2&=\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{k}2\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k(k-1)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(k^2-k)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k^2-\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}6-\frac{(n-1)n}2\right)\\
&=\frac1{12}\big(2n^3-3n^2+n-3n^2+3n\big)\\
&=\frac16n(n-1)(n-2)\;,
\end{align*}$$

using only a couple of summation identities found in most freshman calculus courses.

Finally, one can rewrite the identity as

$$3\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-k}2=n\binom{n-1}2$$

and then as

$$3\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{k}2=n\binom{n-1}2\tag{1}$$

and argue combinatorially as follows.

Suppose that you have players with jerseys numbered from $1$ through $n$, and you want to choose from them a team of $3$ players and appoint one of the $3$ to be captain. There are $n$ ways to choose the captain, and after that there are $\binom{n-1}2$ ways to choose the other $2$ team members from the remaining $n-1$ players, so there are $n\binom{n-1}2$ ways to form a team and appoint its captainn.

Alternatively, we could ask how many ways there are to form a team and appoint its captain if the highest-numbered player on the team is number $k+1$. Then we must choose the other $2$ players from the $k$ players numbered $1$ through $k$, which we can do in $\binom{k}2$ ways; and after that, we can pick any of the $3$ to be the captain, so there are $3\binom{k}2$ ways to pick such a team and appoint its captain. Clearly $k$ must be at least $2$ and at most $n-1$, so the total number of possible teams with appointed captains is $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}3\binom{k}2=3\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{k}2$, proving $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- The denominator does not depend on $k$.
- [Hockeystick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 0):

Begin here:$$\begin{align}\left.\binom{n-k}{2}\middle/\binom{n-1}{2}\right.&=\dfrac{(n-k)!}{2!(n-k-2)!}\cdot\dfrac{2!(n-3)!}{(n-1)!}\end{align}$$

Simplify into a ratio without factorials.

---

Then use the following identities:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}1&=(n-2)\\\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k&=(n-1)(n-2)/2\\\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k^2&=(n-1)(n-2)(2n-3)/6\end{align}$$